# Does GeoIP work when the user is on a mobile network

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, web, geolocation

I'm building a site that tries to workout what city the user is currently in. It does this using their IP address and the GeoIP database.

However, a lot of the users are on mobile networks and was wondering if the location lookup would still be reasonably accurate?

If it wont, is there an alternative?  Ideally something that doesn't prompt the user to access their location like HTML5 geolocation does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a Webservice for an Advertising network, which is accessed only by mobile devices.
We use geoIP for first localization of the user, to get the right language etc.

It is working properly, and we get realy good and accurate positions from geoip database.

The reasen is that also mobile devices are logged-in over local providers. Which has known IP-Addresses.

Hope that helps.

If you can make some test. By locating user over geoip and ask for location over html5 geolocation. Then compare the results. When you are satisfied by the results of geoip, disable html 5 geolocation.

Comment: " mobile devices are logged-in over local providers"  so the IP address location is where the local provider is and not where the mobile user is?  Wouldn't that make it highly inaccurate?

Comment: In most cases the mobile providers have gateways near there radio cells, which means you get a location realy near the cell the phone is logged-in. That is what we see in our data. We can compare geoip with device location service, because in our process the devices later access last known coarse location to make provided advertisments more accurate.